# How do add malayalam context in my website. My client wants all the content in the website to be in malayalam

Tags: html, fonts

My client wants all the content in the website to be in malayalam. The content will be provided in malayalam but i dont know how to implement it in html.

I tried importing malayalam fonts but it is not working. Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Far too broad. What is the issue? Why do you need a special font? Is the content included in the document dynamically or static? is a CMS in use?

Comment: It is using static data the issue was that I was not able to use malayalam (a regional language in india). It was shown as unidentified characters like boxes. Importing google fonts and font supported by google fixed the issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Google Fonts for Malayalam, include the following code in the  section of your HTML document:

```js
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=malayalam&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

To apply the Malayalam font to your content, use CSS to set the font-family for the elements containing Malayalam text. For example, if you want to set the font for the entire body text, you can do this in your CSS:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'malayalam', sans-serif;
}
```

Ensure that your HTML document is using UTF-8 encoding. This is the most widely supported character encoding and will work for Malayalam text.

Include this in your  section:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

When entering Malayalam content into your HTML, you can simply type it using a Malayalam keyboard or copy-paste Malayalam text. The encoding and font settings you've configured should display it correctly

Comment: Yes It worked for me . Thanks :)